# Update pandas dataframe with multiindex based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

trying to update the dataframe:

```py
hist.loc['2021-01-20':'2021-01-22']
```

[image: before update]

, but with

```py
hist.loc['2021-01-20':'2021-01-22']['ETH-USD']['nof'] = 1
```

I still get the same:

[image: after update]

I would expect to have "1"-s in the "nof" column of "ETH-USD" after the update, but there are still "0"-s. Why is that, and how to solve it?

Thanks,
Balazs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use tuples in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select by `MultiIndex`:

```
hist.loc['2021-01-20':'2021-01-22', ('ETH-USD', 'nof')] = 1
```

Why your solution failed is better explain [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy).

Comment: @bayerb - You are welcome!Also added link for explanation why solution failed.